# How to attach class onClick event using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a full AJAX page with elements that act like buttons 
with events like

```
onclick="$('#workcont').load('pages/mypage.html #m3-to-12');"
```

The elements being referenced are `<li>` and `<tr>` (in a table).

How do I attach event handlers to add the class `selected` on click?

Comment: Thanks. Adding class works very good, but nothing chenge visually! Why this may be? I make class .selected in css file with border adding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your page is loaded via AJAX you should attach your events with [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/), so if you want to attach a click event you can do it this way:

```
$("li, tr").live('click', function() {
  $(this).addClass("selected");
});
```

**Update**

> The live() method was deprecated in jQuery version 1.7, and removed in version 1.9 . Use the on() method instead.

```
$("li, tr").on("click",function(){
    $(this).addClass("selected");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can keep the inline `onclick` events and can also add additional `click` handler on those elements using `jQuery`. Try this

```
$("li tr").click(function(){
   $(this).addClass("selected");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Won't

```
 $('#workcont').load('pages/mypage.html #m3-to-12').addClass('selected');
```

work also?

Or are you trying to add the class to a different element?

It *is* a different element. If the element is loaded because of the load() use the callback parameter:

```
$('#workcont').load('pages/mypage.html #m3-to-12', function() { $('li').addClass('selected'); });
```

Comment: Very good example! But it's add class to loaded div with id #workcont, not to clickable element (li). How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the element to be selected as soon as it is clicked use this:

```
$("li, tr").click(function() {
          $("li, tr").removeClass("selected");//To Remove any previuosly selected elements
          $('#workcont').load('pages/mypage.html #m3-to-12'); 
          $(this).addClass("selected");// Select the clicked element
        });
```

If you want the element to be selected as soon as the AJAX page is loaded use this:

```
$("li, tr").click(function() {
          $("li, tr").removeClass("selected");//To Remove any previuosly selected elements
          $(this).addClass("some_temp_unique_class_name");
          $('#workcont').load('pages/mypage.html #m3-to-12', function(response, status, xhr) {
              if (status == "success") {
                var elem = $("li.some_temp_unique_class_name,tr.some_temp_unique_class_name");
                elem.removeClass("some_temp_unique_class_name").addClass("selected");// Select the clicked element
              }
            }); 
        });
```

Refer [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) for more details